# Copying data from an entire column in Excel worksheet into another worksheet minus blank cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

Instead of using the normal copy and paste function, is there a way to lookup data in an entire column (rather than an individual cell) in one spreadsheet and put it in another - minus the blank cells - so it's condensed?

Comment: Yes, there are lots of ways. You could try to write your own VBa. Or you could copy and paste, then filter (to sort the column), remove the empty fields ...

Comment: Wait - do you want to lookup some information? Or do you just want to copy/paste a column's values (ignoring blanks)?  It kinda sounds like you want a copy/paste...but kinda sounds like you're asking for something more in depth.  Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 1):

This is another way without macros or VBA:

1. Select the column
2. Go to Home -> Find & Select -> Go To Special
3. Choose Constants & OK
4. Now, only the cells with a value are selected.
5. Copy & Paste. It's done !!!!

Comment: You just changed my life.

Answer (score 0):

This small macro will copy column **A** from *Sheet1* to column **A** of *Sheet2* omitting the blanks.  Adjust the code for your own columns and sheet names:

```
Sub CopyNoBanks()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet, i As Long
    Dim j As Long, N As Long, r1 As Range

    Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    N = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    j = 1

    For i = 1 To N
        Set r1 = sh1.Cells(i, "A")
        If r1.Value <> "" Then
            r1.Copy sh2.Cells(j, "A")
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**